# How to create doubled start pattern using javascript for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to achieve following pattern using for loops **without relying on external memory outside the loop:**

I want to return `3` zeros, `6` ones and `12` tows and so on..

```js
// the number on the left represents the current index
// the number on the right represents the value that needs to be returned
/*
0 = 0
1 = 0
2 = 0

3 = 1
4 = 1
5 = 1
6 = 1
7 = 1
8 = 1

9 = 2
10 = 2
11 = 2
12 = 2
13 = 2
14 = 2
15 = 2
16 = 2
17 = 2
18 = 2
19 = 2
20 = 2

*/
```

basically this will help me achieve the following star pattern:

```
***
******
************
************************
************************************************
```

I can use the following following but it's not what I really need.

```js
let x = 3;

while (x < 30) {
    console.log(x)

    x = x * 2
}
```

In my case, I have a function that exposes an index prop that increments from 0 to a certain value x:

```js
animation.start(({ index }) => {
   // is it really possible to achieve the above patten (3, 6, 12..) using only the index prop. 
})
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: what does not work? what output do you want?

Comment: This question looks interesting. But unfortunately, no code is provided. Could you share some code you've done so far in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? :)

Comment: why is it so important to not rely on external memory outside the loop? there's a trivial solution that involves allocating an integer just before the loop

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. I just updated the question,

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks I just updated the question

Comment: Back up a little here. What is the problem you actually are solving. What do you expect to see on the screen when you run your program? Don't talk about "return" or anything specific to the programming language. Instead, describe what will be printed to the screen or what the user will enter as input.